# How to save and read special characters in MySql? (Mysqljs & Node)

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I got a node app that's connected directly to a mysql database v 8.18, charset utf8mb4 and collation utf8mb4_unicode_ci.

I'm trying to save special characters just like ä, ü or ö in some columns but within the database those values are changed into e.g. "Ã–" or "Ã¶", which as well results in them not being searchible anymore against the original input.

My connection is setup via the npm package mysqljs as followed:

```
db = mysql.createConnection({
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
  port: process.env.DB_PORT,
  charset: "utf8mb4_unicode_ci"
})
```

while running queries via db.query according to the documentation.

Question now is, what am I doing wrong and what might need to be changed for that to work. 
After all I'm mainly creating a db that saves german and english data.

ADDITION: 
Saving special characters in the db via UI (e.g. db forge Studio) gets me the following error: Incorrect string value: '\xD6sterr...' for column 'Name_de' at row 1

thanks a bunch for your input :)

Comment: Have you tried using the actual db charset in your connection setup?

Comment: Hey Chris, sorry by mistake I copied the code from one of my tests. I'm in general keeping the charset identical to the db setup. As well corrected the code above :)

Comment: I’m not sure about the exact arguments to `createConnection`, but probably `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` is not a valid **charset**, it’s a *collation*. Try just `utf8mb4`…

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the case. It refers to the collation according to the docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql (just utf8mb4 doesn't work either.)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this --> 
https://medium.com/@haotangio/how-to-properly-setup-mysql-5-7-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04-dd4088286016

https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4

problem is utf bytes style used in..

worked for me change from utf8 --> utf8mb4

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't fix my issue. I got the whole database as well as the server set on utf8mb4 already (just like in the post you linked). But unfortunately special characters are still replaced.

Comment: could you send partial code which you are using to save into db. and get from db.